# Perl DBI case insensitive methods

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm trying to make selectall_arrayref subroutine from DBI to return case insensitive hash keys. For example:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:' . 'host','user','pass',
        {
            RaiseError => 1, 
            PrintError => 0,
            AutoCommit => 1
        }
        ) || die( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );
$dbh->do('alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC'); # this doesn't work 
$dbh->do('alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'); # this doesn't work


my $query = 'select test_id from test_table';
my $result = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query, {Slice=>{}});

print(@$result[0]->{TEST_ID}); #works   
print(@$result[0]->{test_id}); #does not work but I want to make it work
print(@$result[0]->{tEsT_Id}); #does not work but I want to make it work
```

I know that DBI has this setting:

```
$dbh->{FetchHashKeyName} = 'NAME_uc' #upper case keys
$dbh->{FetchHashKeyName} = 'NAME_lc' #lower case keys
$dbh->{FetchHashKeyName} = 'NAME' #default
```

Yes, if I set one of these, it works for the respective case, but I want to somehow rewrite the selectall_arrayref subroutine to return keys insenstive, so I could use lower,upper or combined lower and upper case.

How can I achieve something like this?

I would be interested to achieve this on other subroutines too from DBI.

I'm currently using DBD::Oracle for Oracle and DBD::Sybase for Microsoft SQL Server.
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Perl doesn't have case-insensitive strings.

The closest you could come would be to use `NAME_lc` and then pass every value through [`lc`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) before trying to use it as a key name.

Comment: Is there a way to override the subroutines from DBI to force a lowercase on hash keys? 
So when an user requests @$resutls[0]->{hAsHkEy} that 'hAsHkEy' gets to lower case automatically ?

Comment: @rooger That would be what tying the returned data structure would be. But you'd have to tie each hash in the returned array. You could tie each hash with [Tie::CPHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::CPHash): `tie %$_, 'Tie::CPHash' for @$results`. But be warned this may significantly slow down your program. [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Variable::Magic) would be a faster solution but there's no ready made option for this case. -- But in the end, I would just tell the user to lowercase all inputs, this is a common idiom.